# TDateTimePicker Atualização Windows 10

Tags: delphi

Após a atualização do Windows 10 para a versão 15063.38 os campos `TDateTimePicker` passaram a ter um visual desagradável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por mais que eu selecione uma data, ele permanece mostrando somente as barras.

No entanto, em versões como o Windows server 2012, o campo aparece normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém está tendo esse problema e já conseguiu corrigir?

A solução até então está sendo voltar a última atualização do Windows 10.

Comment: Você deu uma olhada se não tem nenhum formato que foi feito para o TDateTimePicker, se eu não me engano tem uma propriedade Format, olha se tem algo preenchido.

Comment: Coloquei dd/MM/yyyy e não resolveu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quem controla os componentes da Paleta Win32 é a OCX **comctl32**.

Para resolver seu problema você terá que copiar esta OCX e colar no lugar da OCX que esta com problema.
Até a Micro$$oft corrigir esse bug a solução mais rápida é esta.

Local: C:\Windows\System32 ou SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx

Recomendo que leve junto a **msconctl.ocx** (que também é responsável por alguns componentes).

Comment: Onde posso encontrar esses arquivos?

Comment: Citei na resposta: `Local: C:\Windows\System32 ou SysWOW64\comctl32.ocx`

Comment: Sim, mas de onde eu posso copiar esses ocx? Só achei dll na pasta antiga da System32 e o msconctl eu não econtrei. E ao tentar substituir a dll da que está sendo usado por outro programa.

Comment: Então, meu Windows por exemplo é 64bts, então tenho a pasta System32 que possui essa DLL e também tenho a pasta SysWOW64 que possui a DLL e a OCX correspondente! Se você não possui a versão de 64bts você deve procurar em todas as pastas pela OCX correspondente, de cabeça eu não lembro onde fica!